# Convert 1D array with coordinates into 2D array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have an array of values `arr` with shape (N,) and an array of coordinates `coords` with shape (N,2). I want to represent this in an (M,M) array `grid` such that `grid` takes the value 0 at coordinates that are not in `coords`, and for the coordinates that are included it should store the sum of all values in `arr` that have that coordinate. So if M=3, `arr = np.arange(4)+1`, and `coords = np.array([[0,0,1,2],[0,0,2,2]])` then `grid` should be:

```
array([[3., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3.],
       [0., 0., 4.]])
```

The reason this is nontrivial is that I need to be able to repeat this step many times and the values in `arr` change each time, and so can the coordinates. Ideally I am looking for a vectorized solution. I suspect that I might be able to use `np.where` somehow but it's not immediately obvious how.

**Timing the solutions**

I have timed the solutions present at this time and it appear that the accumulator method is slightly faster than the sparse matrix method, with the second accumulation method being the slowest for the reasons explained in the comments:

```
%timeit for x in range(100): accumulate_arr(np.random.randint(100,size=(2,10000)),np.random.normal(0,1,10000))
%timeit for x in range(100): accumulate_arr_v2(np.random.randint(100,size=(2,10000)),np.random.normal(0,1,10000))
%timeit for x in range(100): sparse.coo_matrix((np.random.normal(0,1,10000),np.random.randint(100,size=(2,10000))),(100,100)).A
47.3 ms ± 1.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
103 ms ± 255 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
48.2 ms ± 36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
def accumulate_arr(coords, arr):
    # Get output array shape
    m,n = coords.max(1)+1

    # Get linear indices to be used as IDs with bincount
    lidx = np.ravel_multi_index(coords, (m,n))
    # Or lidx = coords[0]*(coords[1].max()+1) + coords[1]

    # Accumulate arr with IDs from lidx
    return np.bincount(lidx,arr,minlength=m*n).reshape(m,n)
```

Sample run -

```
In [58]: arr
Out[58]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [59]: coords
Out[59]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 2, 2]])

In [60]: accumulate_arr(coords, arr)
Out[60]: 
array([[3., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3.],
       [0., 0., 4.]])
```

Another with `np.add.at` on similar lines and might be easier to follow -

```
def accumulate_arr_v2(coords, arr):
    m,n = coords.max(1)+1
    out = np.zeros((m,n), dtype=arr.dtype)
    np.add.at(out, tuple(coords), arr)
    return out
```

Comment: I have tried timing each of the answers so far and v2 here appears to be quite a bit slower, probably because it initializes a new array each time.

Comment: @algol It's the `np.add.at` that slows it down. Go with `bincount`, which is always faster.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to create a `sparse.coo_matrix` and convert that to dense:

```
from scipy import sparse
sparse.coo_matrix((arr,coords),(M,M)).A
# array([[3, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 3],
#        [0, 0, 4]])
```