# How to vectorize increments in Python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a 2d array, and I have some numbers to add to some cells. I want to vectorize the operation in order to save time. The problem is when I need to add several numbers to the same cell. In this case, the vectorized code only adds the last.
'a' is my array, 'x' and 'y' are the coordinates of the cells I want to increment, and 'z' contains the numbers I want to add.

```
import numpy as np

a=np.zeros((4,4))
x=[1,2,1]
y=[0,1,0]
z=[2,3,1]
a[x,y]+=z
print(a)
```

As you see, a[1,0] should be incremented twice: one by 2, one by 1. So the expected array should be:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [3. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 3. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

but instead I get:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 3. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

The problem would be easy to solve with a for loop, but I wonder if I can correctly vectorize this operation.

Comment: the `a[x,y]` works more like a index selection, not an iterator hence, it will not add up index `(1,0)`

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920070/increment-given-indices-in-a-matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) for that:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((4,4))
x = [1, 2, 1]
y = [0, 1, 0]
z = [2, 3, 1]
np.add.at(a, (x, y), z)
print(a)
# [[0. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 3. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing `a[x,y]+=z`, we can decompose the operations as :

```
a[1, 0], a[2, 1], a[1, 0] = [a[1, 0] + 2, a[2, 1] + 3, a[1, 0] + 1]
# Equivalent to :
a[1, 0] = 2
a[2, 1] = 3
a[1, 0] = 1
```

That's why it doesn't works.
But if you're incrementing your array with a loop for each dimention, it should work

Answer (score 0):

You could create a multi-dimensional array of size 3x4x4, then add up `z` to all the 3 different dimensions and them sum them all

```py
import numpy as np
x = [1,2,1]
y = [0,1,0]
z = [2,3,1]
a = np.zeros((3,4,4))
n = range(a.shape[0])
a[n,x,y] += z
print(sum(a))
```

which will result in

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [3. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 3. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach #1: Bincount-based method for performance**

We can use [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) for efficient bin-based summation and basically  inspired by [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56462365/) -

```
def accumulate_arr(x, y, z, out):
    # Get output array shape
    shp = out.shape

    # Get linear indices to be used as IDs with bincount
    lidx = np.ravel_multi_index((x,y),shp)
    # Or lidx = coords[0]*(coords[1].max()+1) + coords[1]

    # Accumulate arr with IDs from lidx
    out += np.bincount(lidx,z,minlength=out.size).reshape(out.shape)
    return out
```

If you are working with a zeros-initialized output array, feed in the output shape directly into the function and get the bincount output as the final one.

Output on given sample -

```
In [48]: accumulate_arr(x,y,z,a)
Out[48]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [3., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 3., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

**Approach #2: Using sparse-matrix for memory-efficiency**

```
In [54]: from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

In [56]: coo_matrix((z,(x,y)), shape=(4,4)).toarray()
Out[56]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

If you are okay with a sparse-matrix, skip the `.toarray()` part for a memory-efficient solution.

Comment: You can save one rather expensive conversion by using `coo_matrix` instead of `csr_matrix` since the data you are passing are in `coo` format.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Is coo_matrix supposed to be faster?

Comment: coo -> dense is faster than coo -> csr -> dense   ---   I see a factor of 5 on a larger example.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yup, seems like it! Edited. From what I remember though that accessing elements off csr was better.